# How to find proper blending mode?

Tags: css, blending

I need a blend mode that gives white text color over a dark background and defined (dark, but not black) color over a light background. If it's not possible, than "white over dark and black over light" would work too.

Here's what I need to achieve:

[image: progress bar]

If there is anything else I could use for this effect (not blending mode, I mean), please also suggest.

Comment: Is this effect even possible to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mix-blend-mode: difference`.

Comment: If I make "color: #fff" + "difference", I get something like the following results: !(https://www.evernote.com/l/ACgS29sxr91PM6GO1UpZ4NPxSBDlqPby5moB/image.png)